# How to send an arrow key in iTerm2

Tags: macos, iterm

Is it possible to send an arrow key in iTerm2? I've been able to send almost any other character, by using either an escape character, such as `\<C-a>` or entering in the character directly, such as `‰`, but I haven't been able to figure out (or find on Google) how to send one of the arrow keys. For example, I would like to configure pressing

- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>

to send a tmux command of:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> (ctrl-a being by prefix)

In other words, pressing cmd-up would navigate to the pane above the current one. How would I do this in iTerm2? That is, what "action" should I select (send hex codes? send text? send text with vim escape chars?) and text/code should I send?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to send an <kbd>↑</kbd> to the terminal, I've been able to accomplish this using the *Send Text with "vim" Special Chars* option and then using the escape sequence `\u000d[A`. For example, I'm using it to clear the console and repeat the last command, so the full sequence I'm sending is:

```
clear\u000d\u001b[A\u001b[A\u000d
```

This first writes `clear` to the console and then submits with <kbd>Enter</kbd> as `\u000d`. Then, <kbd>↑</kbd> is sent twice to get the command submitted before the last `clear` command, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> is sent again to submit the retrieved command.

Hope this helps you. Cheers!

Comment: How to send ←? I tried looking it up and could not find the unicode.

Comment: Found it! \u0002